# Examples of algebra, σ-algebra, and neither

Tags: measure-theory

I've read multiple explanations of the differences between algebras and σ-algebras, but I'm struggling to understand how something with that deals with things that are "countably infinite" (σ-algebras) can be a subset of something that deals with finite things (algebras).  If σ-algebras are subsets of algebra and not all collections are algebras, there should be three relevant classes:

1. Neither algebra nor σ-algebra
2. Algebra but not σ-algebra
3. Both algebra and σ-algebra

Can someone list out three similar collections with slight differences and explain how the differences determine which category that each is in?  Specifically, what is the requirement for a collection to be a σ-algebra that is not present in other algebras?

I'm aware that all algebras must include $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ and that each $A$ must have an $A^c$.

Comment: It is a misconception that a $\sigma$-algebra is "countably infinite". The first thing one learns about them is that $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ is one.

Answer (score 1):

So, rather than give three examples out of the blue, I'm going to start with a non-algebra and add sets to the collection until we get a $\sigma$-algebra.

Let's start with the collection

$$\{(a,b]\mid a< b \in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}\}$$

Of half-closed (not necessarily finite) intervals. This is not an algebra, nor a $\sigma$-algebra, as it is not closed under taking any unions or complements.

We we consider the collection of finite unions of such sets, we get an algebra - it is closed under finite unions by definition, and
$$(a,b]^c =(-\infty,a]\cup(b,\infty]$$
so it is closed under complements.

But it is not closed under countable unions:
$$\cup_{n\geq 2} (0,1-\frac{1}{n}] = (0,1)$$
is not in the collection. So in order to complete the to a $\sigma$ algebra, we also need to include all open and (to preserve complements) closed intervals of the real line too.

Hopefully that helps. As for why $\sigma$-algebras are a subset of algebras: every $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable unions, and hence closed under finite unions. Hence every $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra.

Comment: It's worth noting that it is possible to add sets to a $\sigma$-algebra and have the resulting larger collection be an algebra that is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Incidentally, it's easy to find examples where you add a set to a $\sigma$-algebra and the resulting larger collection is not a $\sigma$-algebra (e.g. add a non-measurable set to the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets; then the complement of this non-measurable set is also non-measurable but doesn't belong to the larger collection), which is why I included the additional condition that the larger collection is an algebra.

Comment: Is it not possible or not practical to give an example in the form of $\{\emptyset, \Omega, A, A^c\}$ or similar?  If not, maybe explaining why it's not would actually help.  Phrases like "closed under taking any unions or complements" are comprised of all common English words but the phrase has a meaning that is specific to this context.  I would bet a small fortune that the issue is not that the concepts are difficult but that the meaning is lost in translation.

Comment: As another example, this is how I understood σ-algebras to be defined until it was mentioned that there are other algebras that are not σ-algebras:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19302/explanation-of-term-closed-under-in-the-definition-of-a-sigma-algebra.  On its own this explanation makes sense, but it doesn't address the difference between algebras and σ-algebras.  For example, if σ-algebras can be "countably infinite" and finite things are countable, then it stands to reason that finite things are a subset of countable things, not the other way around.

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah To address the difference between sigma algebras and algebras: it is not that sigma algebras are necessarily countably infinite - it's that they contain all countably infinite unions. A finite sigma algebra admits all countably infinite unions as it only has finite unions. An algebra can be countably infinite, but not contain all countably infinite unions, as illustrated by something like half intervals on the rationals. The difference is in the type of unions we can take, not the size of the algebra

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah: *Is it not possible or not practical to give an example in the form of* $\{\emptyset, \Omega, A, A^c\}$ *or similar? If not, maybe explaining why it's not would actually help* --- It is not possible to give an example in which the algebra only contains a finite number of elements (which themselves are sets, of course). For instance, if a collection of a finite number of sets is closed under the operation of taking the union of two sets in the collection **(continued)**

Comment: (and hence, by easy mathematical induction, the collection of sets is closed under the operation of taking the union of any finite number of sets in the collection), then it automatically follows that the collection of sets is closed under the operation of taking the union of **any indexed collection** (no restriction -- finitely or infinitely many sets can belong to the indexed collection) of sets in the collection. Basically it comes down to the fact that regardless of how many sets are involved in the indexed collection, the union can be replaced by a union of finitely many distinct sets.